# How to change checkbox label value in DevEcoStudio Previewer according to selected language?

Tags: harmonyos

I am using DevEco Studio 3.0.0.800, I created a select form element and added an option od datetime which launches a datetime picker. The default datetime picker changes according to language but the checkbox inside the picker remains in Chinese. I have tried changing it to multiple languages but it remains Chinese.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Add a select option of 'datetime' and a datetime picker
2. Click on 'datetime'
3. Click on '...' to change the language
4. Open the datetime picker again
5. The label for given checkbox is still in chinese

**Expected behavior**

The label for the given Checkbox should change according to the language selected.

Here is my code:

**index.hml**

```
<div class="container">
    <select @change="selectChange">
        <option value="{{ item }}" for="item in selectList">
            {{ item }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <picker id="picker0" type="datetime" value="{{datetimevalue}}" selected="{{datetimeselect}}" hours="24" lunarswitch="true"
            onchange="datetimeonchange" oncancel="datetimeoncancel" class="pickerdatetime" show="false"></picker>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
export default {
    data: {
        title: "",
        selectList:["datetime"],
    },
    selectChange(e){
        this.$element("picker0").show();

    },
    onInit() {
        this.title = this.$t('strings.world');
    }
}
```

Error Image：

[image]

Comment: Could you kindly help us with some information to locate this issue? 
1. The SDK version you have integrated.
2. Does the problem occur on the real device or previewer？
3. If is a real device, what was the device model and image version.
4. Is the application Ace1.0 or 2.0, OpenHarmony or HarmonyOS?

Comment: The related document has been updated. You can try again by referring to [this docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/ts-basic-components-datepicker-0000001333641061).